# Explain this step (related to gamma matrices and parity operator)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, parity

I am having hard time reproducing a step from the textbook "Lecture Notes on Quantum Field Theory", by Ashok Das. On page 429 ( above equation 11.72), the author is talking about the parity operation acting on the Dirac field. We assume that the Dirac field transforms like this under parity:

$$ \psi_\alpha(x,t) \rightarrow \pm S^\beta_\alpha \psi_\beta(-x,t) $$

The matrix S is unknown. To figure out S, the author calculates the conserved current $J^\mu$ associated with the Dirac field in two different ways and then compares their time and spacial components separately.

By comparing the time component of the Dirac current, he establishes:
\begin{equation} S = S^\dagger = S^{-1} \tag{11.71}\end{equation}
Then he compares the spatial components and obtains:
\begin{equation}  \bar{\psi}(-x,t) \gamma^0 S^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^i S \psi(-x,t) = - \bar{\psi}(-x,t) \gamma^i \psi(-x,t) \tag{unnumbered}\end{equation}
And then he says that it implies:
\begin{equation} S = \gamma^0 \tag{11.72}\end{equation}

It's not clear to me how the author jumped to (11.72) from the unnumbered equation.

This is how I would proceed from the unnumbered equation:
$$  \gamma^0 S^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^i S  = - \gamma^i $$
Substituting (11.71):
$$  \gamma^0 S \gamma^0 \gamma^i S  = - \gamma^i $$
$$ \implies ( \gamma^0 S )  \gamma^i ( \gamma^0 S ) = \gamma^i $$
How do we conclude (11.72) from here?

Note:
The textbook is using mostly negative metric. So, $\gamma^0 \gamma^0 = 1, \gamma^1 \gamma^1 = -1$, etc